# Representing numbers greater than 65535 in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am working in MIPS, and using numbers in excess of 65535, and I'm getting an out of range error. How can I work around that in this code?

```
## p2.asm
##
## Andrew Levenson, 2010
## Problem 2 from Project Euler
## In MIPS Assembly, for SPIM
##
## Calculate the sum, s of all
## even valued terms in the
## Fibonacci sequence which
## do not exceed 4,000,000
        .text
        .globl  main

main:
    ## Registers
        ori     $t0, $0, 0x0        # $t0 will contain scratch
        ori     $t1, $0, 0x1        # $t1 will contain initial fib(N-1) 
        ori     $t2, $0, 0x2        # $t2 will contain initial fib(N) 
        ori     $t3, $0, 0x0        # $t3 will be our loop incrementor
        ori     $t4, $0, 0x0        # $t4 will be our sum
        ori     $t5, $0, 0x2        # $t5 contains two to test if even
        ori     $t8, $0, 4000000    # $t8 contains N limit

even_test:  
    ## Test to see if a given number is even
        div     $t1, $t5            # $t1 / 2
        mflo    $t6                 # $t6 = floor($t1 / 2) 
        mfhi    $t7                 # $t7 = $t1 mod 2

        bne     $t7, $0, inc        # if $t7 != 0 then bypass sum
        sll     $0, $0, $0          # no op


sum:
    ## Add a given value to the sum
        addu    $t4, $t4, $t2       # sum = sum + fib(N)

inc:
    ## Increment fib's via xor swap magic
        xor     $t1, $t1, $t2       # xor swap magic
        xor     $t2, $t1, $t2       # xor swap magic
        xor     $t1, $t1, $t2       # xor swap magic
    ## Now $t1 = $t2 and $t2 = $t1

    ## Increment $t2 to next fib
        addu    $t2, $t1, $t2

    ## Is $t2 < 4,000,000?
    ## If so, go to loop
        sltu    $8, $t2, $t8        # If $t2 < 4,000,000 
                                    # then $8 = 1
        bne     $8, $0, even_test   # if $8 == $0 then jump to even_test
        sll     $0, $0, $0          # no op

print:
        li      $v0, 0x1            # system call #1 - print int
        move    $a0, $t4
        syscall                     # execute

        li      $v0, 0xA            # system call #10 - exit
        syscall

## End of Program
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I had no idea of MIPS assembly before yesterday, but I'll give a shot)

LUI with 0x3D, followed by ORI with 0x900 (4,000,000 being 0x3D0900)?

Comment: +1.  You should be able to simply write `li $t8, 4000000`, but that's exactly what it will expand to.

Comment: I'd have to throw in a left shift before the or, but yeah, this works, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't need any left shift with LUI.

Comment: My bad. Also, oh man oh man oh man I got the last kinks out and it works! I never thought even 30 minutes ago that I'd actually get a working solution for this in MIPS. :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is the problem line?

```
   ori     $t8, $0, 4000000    # $t8 contains N limit
```

MIPS instructions have only 16-bit constant fields, so you need to construct constants greater than 65535 with a more complex sequence, or else load them from memory.  Something like this should work:

```
  ori      $t8, $0, 0x3d09     # 4 000 000 >> 8
  sll      $t8, $t8, 8
```

I *think* "sll dest, src, count" is how you shift left in MIPS assembly, but I could be wrong.  You can also use the "li" macro-instruction, which takes any 32-bit constant and finagles that into a register somehow, using more than one instruction if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed that problem (I think). Now I just need to figure out why it's spitting out the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to use two registers, one for the higher-order bits and one-for the lower-order bits.  You'd have to keep track of them together, but that's just what comes to mind for me.